# Transpose With Multiple Criteria Big Data Set

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have a big dataset I am working with. Column A B and C all have multiple criteria. I am having an issue transposing it into a new table. I have tried INDEX, INDEX MATCH and TRANSPOSE but keep getting a #Reference. I have also tried looking up a Google App Script but no luck. I have worked on it for several days now and am now turing for some help.

If there is anyone that can give me any insight or guidance that would be really helpful.

Here is an mock example of what I am trying to do.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ViPCEet5i19YBQID4Uv-iu8JZrP33eHwx1eQcv4bUOE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit clumsy but if you just need it as a one off you can add a column that concatenates the two things you are looking up (store number & fruit), which will let you use index match.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wApPtvbNdFRbXfpk2xo_6HSWnJvu4l_Ii-i34RbYUeM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach added to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ViPCEet5i19YBQID4Uv-iu8JZrP33eHwx1eQcv4bUOE/edit#gid=973071253):

```
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),Δ,unique(torow(B2:B,1),1),
       {{"Store #";Σ},{Δ;makearray(counta(Σ),counta(Δ),lambda(r,c,+filter(C2:C,A2:A=index(Σ,r),B2:B=index(Δ,,c))))}})
```

[image]